# Как вычислить разницу дней и часов между двумя датами в формате 1 день 4 часа и 2 минуты?

Tags: дата, android, время

Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно вычислить разницу между двумя датами, но чтобы результат не был в виде 1 день 24 часа 1440 минут, а был в виде 1 день 4 часа и 2 минуты.
Т.е. округлялось до дней, потом часов и минут?
Не знаю понятно ли я написала..

в общем вот что у меня получилось, но здесь результат именно, что разница в датах просто переводится в дни, часы и минуты.

```
String dateStartOn = etDateStart.getText().toString();  
String timeStartOn = etTimeStart.getText().toString();
String dateStartTo = etDateEnd.getText().toString(); 
String timeStartTo = etTimeEnd.getText().toString();

        //* форматируем Дату начала 
        SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        SimpleDateFormat sdf3 = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
        Date dS = null;
        Date tS = null;
        try {
          dS = sdf1.parse(dateStartOn); 
          tS = sdf3.parse(timeStartOn);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
          System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }

        Calendar dayStart = Calendar.getInstance();
        dayStart.setTime(dS); //rest is the same...
        dayStart.setTime(tS);

        //* форматируем Дату конца 
        SimpleDateFormat sdf2 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        SimpleDateFormat sdf4 = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");

        Date dE = null;
        Date tE = null;
        try {
          dE = sdf2.parse(dateStartTo);
          tE = sdf4.parse(timeStartTo);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
          System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }

        Calendar dayEnd = Calendar.getInstance();
        dayEnd.setTime(dE); //rest is the same....
        dayEnd.setTime(tE);

        long diff = dayEnd.getTimeInMillis() - dayStart.getTimeInMillis(); //result in millis
        long days = diff / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000); // approximation
        long hours = diff / (60 * 60 * 1000); // approximation
        long minutes = diff / (60 * 1000);
```

Comment: long diffSeconds = diff / 1000 % 60;
   long diffMinutes = diff / (60 * 1000) % 60;
   long diffHours = diff / (60 * 60 * 1000) % 24;
   long diffDays = diff / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);

Answer (score 3):

Была такая же задача получить разницу во времени, только время получал сразу в Date, но это не принципиально. Так же использовал Calendar и вот что получилось:

```
Calendar diff = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
diff.setTimeInMillis(endDate.getTime() - startDate.getTime());
Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Work Time: " + getCoolTime(diff));

public String getCoolTime(Calendar time) {
return (time.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR) - 1) + "d "
+ time.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) + ":"
                + time.get(Calendar.MINUTE) + ":" + time.get(Calendar.SECOND);
    }
```